# Control file name of UIImage send with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm sharing an image, along with a url and some text, with a `UIActivityViewController`. Everything works great, except the image file name is always 'Image-1' with no extension. In some cases this causes a big problem, such as in the mail app which won't open an image without an extension at all.

The image is being generated by the application and exists as a `UIImage`.

Is there a way to control the file name and add the correct extension to the image?

Answer (score 0):

If its application generated image (`UIImage` reference), then you can use below code:

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) mimeType:@"" fileName:@"myImage.png"];
```

I have used the same code for my project, where one can create your own *PNG* format image with `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` method.

If you require *JPEG* image then use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` method. Then change the filename in above method with `.jpg` extension.

For more details regarding both the methods, refer [UIKit Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks! I had just tried this and it fixes the issue with the mail app. After creating the jpeg data, how would I go about changing the file name though? `UIActivityViewController` has no analogous way to name an attachment.

Comment: I mean to change the extension to jpg here in filename property- [mailComposer addAttachmentData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage,1.0f) mimeType:@"" fileName:@"myImage.jpg"];

Comment: Right, however I'm using a `UIActivityViewController` to email the image, so I can't manually attach the image to the mail composer in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware to control the filename or the encoding type of a UIImage is to save it to a file on the device, and then feed the URL of the file into the UIActivityViewController. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826633/406797) for code you can use to accomplish this. This approach has some obvious drawbacks, but will probably be good enough for most applications.