# How to send a PDF file using UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to send a PDF using a `UIActivityViewController`. So far everything works fine using a fairly basic approach but the one issue I have is that when I select the send by mail option, the PDF's file name is `Attachment-1` rather than `Calculation.PDF` which is the name that I give the file.

I don't mind too much the change in title, but the lack of a .pdf extension does seem to cause a problem when sending the file to people with Windows PC's and I'd like to fix that.

I've had a look at:
[Control file name of UIImage send with UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479284/control-file-name-of-uiimage-send-with-uiactivityviewcontroller)

But can't see an equivalent method to:

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) mimeType:@"" fileName:@"myImage.png"];
```

that will work with a PDF file. Is this something that is not fixable without customization or is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi ever figure this one out? Having the same issue.

Comment: This helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825777/uiactivityviewcontroller-sharing-image-via-email-has-no-extension/15826633#15826633 , but drawback is, that you have to save the file first.

Answer (score 67):

try this

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFilePath];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", pdfData] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and also

```
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppDistributionGuide" ofType:@"pdf"];   
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str]] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: @iTroyd23, i tried with your suggestion but i can't set attachment's title. so, can you describe how to set attachment's title (e.g. myPdf.pdf)

Comment: Just to say I tried both and NSURL worked best for me for an XML file.

Answer (score 19):

**Swift**

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fileName)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url] , applicationActivities: nil)
        
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 14):

## Swift 4.0

Here I attached code.I just added thread handling in to present "activityViewController" because of this viewcontroller present before load actual data.

```
let url = NSURLfileURL(withPath:fileName)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url] , applicationActivities: nil)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Above listing about Swift is deprecated in Swift 3

```
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: fileName)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url] , applicationActivities: nil)

present(activityViewController,
    animated: true,
    completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Objective-C tested code to share PDF**

```
- (void)downloadPDFfile:(NSString *)fileName withFileURL:(NSString *)shareURL {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
        NSString *filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[self generateName:fileName withFiletype:@"pdf"]]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:shareURL]];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
                                          } else if (data && error == nil) {
                                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                  [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                                                  [self shareFile:fileName withFilepath:filePath];
                                              });
                                          }
                                      }];

        [task resume];
    });
}

-(void)shareFile:(NSString*)withfileName withFilepath:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (filePath) {
        [items addObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    }

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
    [activityViewController setValue:withfileName forKey:@"subject"];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController;
        popPC.sourceView = self.view;
        CGRect sourceRext = CGRectZero;
        sourceRext.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width-30, 0);
        popPC.sourceRect = sourceRext;
        popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
    }

    [activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:
     ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {

     }];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(NSString*)generateName:(NSString*)title withFiletype:(NSString*)type {
    NSString *subject = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
    subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",subject,type];
    return subject;
}
```

**call function like below**

```
[self downloadPDFfile:@"yourFileName" withFileURL:shareURL];
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 3**

You have to have a `URL` array with the path of the PDF you want to send.

```
let urlArray = [pdfPath1, pdfPath2]
```

Then create an `UIActivityViewController`:

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: urlArray, applicationActivities: nil)
```

If you are using a `UIBarButtonItem` to make that action, you can implement this to prevent an error on iPad:

```
if let popover = activityController.popoverPresentationController {
   popover.barButtonItem = self.barButtonItem
}
```

Finally you have to present the `activityController`:

```
self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reply by Muruganandham K is simple and quite elegant. However, it doesn't work in iOS 9. In order to make it work, if you remove the `@[@"Test"` and just pass the pdfData, an attachment is made.

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFilePath];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:pdfData applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -3):

May be try this..

```
    #define IS_IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

    // Validate PDF using NSData
    - (BOOL)isValidePDF:(NSData *)pdfData {
        BOOL isPDF = false;
        if (pdfData.length >= 1024 ) {

            int startMetaCount = 4, endMetaCount = 5;
            // check pdf data is the NSData with embedded %PDF & %%EOF
            NSData *startPDFData = [NSData dataWithBytes:"%PDF" length:startMetaCount];
            NSData *endPDFData = [NSData dataWithBytes:"%%EOF" length:endMetaCount];
            // startPDFData, endPDFData data are the NSData with embedded in pdfData
            NSRange startRange = [pdfData rangeOfData:startPDFData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1024)];
            NSRange endRange = [pdfData rangeOfData:endPDFData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, pdfData.length)];

            if (startRange.location != NSNotFound && startRange.length == startMetaCount && endRange.location != NSNotFound && endRange.length == endMetaCount ) {
                // This assumes the checkstartPDFData doesn't have a specific range in file pdf data
                isPDF = true;

            } else  {
                isPDF = false;
            }
        }
        return isPDF;
    }

    // Download PDF file in asynchronous way and validate pdf file formate.
    - (void)downloadPDFfile:(NSString *) fileName withFileURL:(NSString *) url {
        NSString *filePath = @"";
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
            filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Attachments/%@",[self generateName:fileName withFiletype:@"pdf"]]];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
                } else if (data && error == nil) {
                    bool checkPdfFormat = [self isValidePDF:data];
                    if (checkPdfFormat) {
                        //saving is done on main thread
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                            [self triggerShare:fileName withFilepath:filePath];
                        });
                    }
                }
            }];
        });
    }

    // Trigger default share and print functionality using UIActivityViewController
    -(void) triggerShare:(NSString*)fileName withFilepath:(NSString*)filePath {
            * Set this available field on the activity controller */
            NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (filePath) {
                [items addObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
            }

            UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
            [activityViewController setValue:fileName forKey:@"subject"]; // Set the mail subject.


            if (IS_IPAD) {
                activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
                UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController;
                popPC.sourceView = self.view;
                CGRect sourceRext = CGRectZero;
                sourceRext.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width-30, 0 ); // I have share button in navigation bar. ;)
                popPC.sourceRect = sourceRext;
                popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
            }


            [activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:
             ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
             }];
            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    -(NSString*) generateName:(NSString*)title withFiletype:(NSString*)type {

        NSString *subject = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
        subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",subject,type];
        return subject;
    }
```