# How does iOS open PDF's in the Mail app?

Tags: ios, pdf, ios10, apple-mail

Does the Mail app on iOS use UIDocumentInteractionController() to open a pdf from within Mail in iOS 10??

Comment: Instead of posting a question asking what some other app may or may not do, you should post a real question asking about something you are trying to do.

Comment: I did have another question which went unanswered so I am trying to get to a solution, thus asking if anyone knows which controller Apple uses to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure, but it probably uses either that or `UIWebView`.

**EDIT**: If you want to share a PDF too, then you should be able to do that using UIActivityViewController with its activityItems just set to the PDF. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15781877/3398839).

Comment: are you able to add the Share functionality to UIWebView?

Comment: As in sharing the PDF to Messages, to example? Yes, you should be able to do that using `UIActivityViewController` with its `activityItems` just set to the PDF. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15781877/3398839).

Comment: @Coder256 Your current answer is really just a comment. Your first comment below your answer is much more of an answer. You should edit your answer to include that information.