# Unable to share doc /ppt /Xlsx using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am unable to share the msword and msexcel and ppt files in Swift Using UIActivityViewController

Here is the code snippet I am using

```
func ShareFileFromApptoIpad(filename : String!){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentoPath = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(filename!)")

    print("doc\(documentoPath)")

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentoPath){
        let documento = NSData(contentsOfFile: documentoPath)
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documento!], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("document was not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Use let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: myFileName) and then pass this url to activityItems of UIActivityViewController.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781877/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-using-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Above method is working fine for PDF and Image sharing only problem is msword /msexcel/ppt file share

Comment: Thanks for your  suggestion the first suggestion working in all scenarios

Answer (score 2):

you can change your url Like this

```
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: myFileName)
```

and then use in

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url] , applicationActivities: nil)
```