# webview loaded pdf file from remotly then how to send this pdf file via mail and all that? (SWIFT 4)

Tags: ios, pdf, swift4, alamofire

I am a new developer in swift, so please help me.

I am open a pdf file from remote server through Alamofire, then i needed to send this opened pdf file in webview so how it can be possible to send via mail,whatsapp,etc.from my app.

Comment: have you tried this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781877/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-using-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: yes but it's not working may be i can't understand this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a PDF file using UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781877/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-using-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: when webview load PDF file on specific remote  location then i want to share PDF file without download it can be possible or not?