# UIActivityViewController sharing image via email has no extension

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

The image attached is just "Attachment-1", no extension. How do I specify one ?

```
    NSData *compressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.resultImage, 0.8 );

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ @"Check this out!", compressedImage ] applicationActivities:nil];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13028336/846273) you should be able to use this workaround to specify a filename

```
NSData *compressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.resultImage, 0.8 );
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];
NSURL *imageUrl     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];

[compressedImage writeToURL:imageUrl atomically:YES]; // save the file
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ @"Check this out!", imageUrl ] applicationActivities:nil];
```

The obvious drawback of this approach is that you will have to save the image on disk.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. It's annoying that Apple doesn't take this kind of functionality more seriously. Somebody at Google needs to give them a lesson on sandboxed app interop, Android has been doing this so well since the beginning with Intents. ... *~sigh~* hopefully iOS 7 changes it.

Comment: This helps for sharing .png files as well! When you just share a UIImage, it is converted into a jpeg automatically. Great solution!

Comment: If you pass the NSData of the image in the activityItems array it also works. You don't need to actually write out to a file then.

Comment: @timeuser but it does not allow you to change the filename, except for having a default image1.jpg ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. If I pass the file name in the activity items array then it just tries to save 2 files... one is a text document containing the name, and the other is the actual file/data I'm trying to save.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to timeuser's suggestion, converting UIImage to NSData.

```
NSData * data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(original,1.0);
UIActivityViewController * activity =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Your Text", data] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activity animated:true completion:^{ }];
```