# How do I share an image on iOS and Android using Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to share an image using the standard share dialogs in iOS and Android. The code below is mostly from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share which I'm using as a starting point (only Dart and Objective-C below). It currently shares only text.

Instead of Image below which I'm not sure is the best approach, how would I convert the image to a byte stream in Dart and handle in iOS and Android.

Dart

```
static const _kShareChannel = const MethodChannel('example.test.com/share');
Future<Null> shareImage(Image image) {
  assert(image != null);
  return _kShareChannel.invokeMethod('shareImage', image);
}
```

Objective-C

```
static NSString *const PLATFORM_CHANNEL = @"example.test.com/share";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];

    FlutterViewController* controller = (FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;

    FlutterMethodChannel *shareChannel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:PLATFORM_CHANNEL
                            binaryMessenger:controller];

    [shareChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall *call, FlutterResult result) {
        if ([@"shareImage" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
            [self share:call.arguments withController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
            result(nil);
        } else {
            result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"UNKNOWN_METHOD"
                                       message:@"Unknown share method called"
                                       details:nil]);
        }
    }];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)share:(id)sharedItems withController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ sharedItems ]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
    [controller presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16743

Comment: @DuncanJones what do you need exactly ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet As a relative newcomer to Flutter, I didn't understand Collin's answer and wasn't sure how to proceed. So I guess I'm looking for a more detailed walk through of the tasks involved; where there might be a need for native code vs what can be achieved in Flutter, etc.

Comment: @DuncanJones does alardizabel's answer below help with your question? I guess that boils down to: what is the source of the image you want to share? The answer shows it coming from an asset. What's your use case? Captured from the camera? Downloaded over http? Generated in memory using a proprietary codec? Do you have an encoded image (jpeg, png, etc) or a raw raster that needs encoding, or something else? If the answer here doesn't help, perhaps ask your own question. Incidentally, does this help you with your vCard question? If not, another question...

Comment: @RichardHeap The answer looks helpful (and will likely claim the bounty). In my specific case, the image I want to share is already a file in the apps document directory, but I'm sure I can figure out the remaining gaps myself.

Comment: @DuncanJones Using the documents directory would just mean swapping out `getTemporaryDirectory` with `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` on the dart side, `NSDocumentDirectory` instead of `NSCachesDirectory` on iOS. On Android, it’s a little trickier. `getFilesDir` is the simplest way to access the file system on Android, but the current path provider flutter plugin corresponds to `getDir`. You would also need to update `file_paths.xml`. This should be part of a plugin but it needs work on where to store files, valid file types, and cases of text only, image only, text and images, etc.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The below will allow you to send a file (specifically an image in this example) using `UIActivityViewController` on iOS and as a share intent on Android.

[FileProvider overview (Android)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Update `pubspec.yaml` to reference your image if local (image.jpg in this example) and to use the `path_provider` plugin in order to access the file system. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Share Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Share Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _shareImage,
        tooltip: 'Share',
        child: new Icon(Icons.share),
      ),
    );
  }

  _shareImage() async {
    try {
      final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.jpg');
      final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.jpg').create();
      file.writeAsBytesSync(list);

      final channel = const MethodChannel('channel:me.albie.share/share');
      channel.invokeMethod('shareFile', 'image.jpg');

    } catch (e) {
      print('Share error: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

static NSString *const SHARE_CHANNEL = @"channel:me.albie.share/share";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
    FlutterViewController* controller = (FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;

    FlutterMethodChannel *shareChannel =
    [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:SHARE_CHANNEL
                                binaryMessenger:controller];

    [shareChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall *call, FlutterResult result) {
        if ([@"shareFile" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
            [self shareFile:call.arguments
             withController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
        }
    }];

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)shareFile:(id)sharedItems withController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    NSMutableString *filePath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:sharedItems];
    NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ shareImage ]
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
    [controller presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.share;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    private static final String SHARE_CHANNEL = "channel:me.albie.share/share";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

        new MethodChannel(this.getFlutterView(), SHARE_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            public final void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (methodCall.method.equals("shareFile")) {
                    shareFile((String) methodCall.arguments);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void shareFile(String path) {
        File imageFile = new File(this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), path);
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "me.albie.share", imageFile);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="me.albie.share"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="images" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Why don't you combine all the native ode and make a flutter plugin? Please do that. It's difficult for a people like me to Flutter

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me.I'm very happy. I'm upvoting this answer now!!

Comment: Please, create a plugin with this functionality, there's no plugins with that functionality, share files. Is hard to us that have no experience with IOS. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, anyone, create the plugin, or fix the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/advanced_share plugin that is broken at the moment. I tried to use this answer, but without proper Android knowledge this is too complicated to debug.

Comment: When I used your flutter code, I got the following exception upon clicking on my button: 

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method shareFile on channel channel:me.albie.share/share)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: @bangbang, search for `shareFile` in the `AppDelegate` or `MainActivity` above depending on what platform you're referring to. In the method call handlers, there are `if` checks to match up the method calls you're making from Flutter to native. The arguments are passed as strings. You're seeing that error possibly because of a typo of the `shareFile` strings or you didn't include the code to handle the call.

Comment: But I thought I just have to copy paste the flutter code you shared and that's all.

Comment: . I am developing an app using dart and flutter. So, that's why I copied the flutter code in the hopes that it will work.

Comment: @bangbang The above uses native code and platform channels. You can also try the plugin mentioned below.

Comment: Thank you this code is very helpful but how to send an image with text using this method

Comment: Pls renew your answer. I got lot of error im my code..

Comment: I have upvoted it but your suggested channel is not working. final channel = const MethodChannel('channel:me.albie.share/share');
      channel.invokeMethod('shareFile', 'image.jpg');

Comment: i tried all plugins for share a pdf from local mobile folder to whatsapp/gmail in 2022 all are outdated . nothing working .

Answer (score 13):

We put that functionality into a plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/esys_flutter_share.

Dart:

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png');
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @albert-lardizabal for the code above it works just perfect!! I had to translate it to Swift and Kotlin, so here's the code in case you guys need it:

Swift:

```
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)


    let shareChannelName = "channel:me.albie.share/share";
    let controller:FlutterViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
    let shareChannel:FlutterMethodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel.init(name: shareChannelName, binaryMessenger: controller);

    shareChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
        (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
        if (call.method == "shareFile") {
            self.shareFile(sharedItems: call.arguments!,controller: controller);
        }
    });


    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func shareFile(sharedItems:Any, controller:UIViewController) {
    let filePath:NSMutableString = NSMutableString.init(string: sharedItems as! String);
    let docsPath:NSString = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]) as NSString;
    let imagePath = docsPath.appendingPathComponent(filePath as String);
    let imageUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: imagePath, relativeTo: nil);
    do {
        let imageData = try Data.init(contentsOf: imageUrl);
        let shareImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData);
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: [shareImage!], applicationActivities: nil);
        controller.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

    MethodChannel(flutterView,"channel:me.albie.share/share").setMethodCallHandler { methodCall, _ ->
        if (methodCall.method == "shareFile") {
            shareFile(methodCall.arguments as String)
        }
    }
}

private fun shareFile(path:String) {
    val imageFile = File(this.applicationContext.cacheDir,path)
    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"me.albie.share",imageFile)

    val shareIntent = Intent()
    shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    shareIntent.type="image/jpg"
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Compartir usando"))
}
```

Comment: Please, i'd like to ask you some questions about your code, 
1. can you do a lib of it to we use in the yaml file? or 
2. Can you edit the post to show step by step how to do it working on a project? and 
3. This code works with local and remote files?
4. it works only for image or for any type of file?

thank you in advance..

Comment: how to send image with text in social media like whats app

Answer (score 8):

Try using [wc_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/wc_flutter_share).


https://pub.dev/packages/wc_flutter_share


This plugin supports sharing image, text and subject. Unique thing about this plugin is that it also supports sharing image and text simultaneously which other plugins don't support at the time I am writing this answer.

Comment: same as esys_flutter_share plugin: Your flutter's iOS code needs to be in swift.

Comment: @AlessandroSantamaria - not the same as esys_flutter_share .. I could not get esys to show Subject on an email share. The image/video/audio would come across fine to email app, as well as body text, but the subject was always blank. WcFlutterShare works with subject, and works across any app I've shared content with, for sharing images, video, text and audio .. to email, hangouts, whatsapp, skype etc

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, you should use [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) , the official Share plugin. It's reliable and easy to use.

Import the library.

```
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
```

Then invoke the static share method anywhere in your Dart code.

```
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');
```

The share method also takes an optional subject that will be used when sharing to email.

```
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com', subject: 'Look what I made!');
```

To share one or multiple files invoke the static shareFiles method anywhere in your Dart code. Optionally you can also pass in text and subject.

```
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image.jpg'], text: 'Great picture');
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image1.jpg', '${directory.path}/image2.jpg']);
```

Comment: What is this `directory.path`?

Comment: @AbbasJafari `directory.path` is where you save the image to. Usually, the `directory` can be the app document directory and be gotten by calling `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the image file is downloaded, I would recommend saving it to a temporary file in Dart.

```
await new File('${systemTempDir.path}/foo.jpg').create();
```

Then you can invoke `UIActivityViewController` with a URL representing the filename of the image file. Here's some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825777/uiactivityviewcontroller-sharing-image-via-email-has-no-extension/15826633#15826633) on how to do this in a non-Flutter app that should get you started.

If your image file is constructed dynamically (e.g. using the `Canvas` API), you may be wondering how to encode a [`ui.Image`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) object into an image file. The Flutter engine doesn't currently provide a way to do that, it would be possible modify the engine to add that support. You can take a look at how [screenshot](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/common/platform_view_service_protocol.cc#L269) support is implemented for inspiration, but it won't be trivial.

Comment: Use this to get temporary path `(await getTemporaryDirectory()).absolute.path`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following flutter plugin:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share

Text sharing is quite simple:

```
Share.share('Text I wish to share');
```

For image:
Better convert an image to Base64 string and send as a string.

Comment: You cannot share a Base64 String with the Flutter Share Plugin. I have tried it, all that happens it shares the Base64 String as text :/

Comment: in 2022 i want to share pdf file from device local folder to gmail, and whatsapp. not an single solution worked for me. class FlutterShare2 {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('flutter_share');

  static Future<bool?> shareFile({
    required String filePath,
  }) async {
    assert(filePath.isNotEmpty);

    final success = await _channel.invokeMethod('shareFile', <String, dynamic>{
      'filePath': filePath,
    });return success;
  }
}     ///  await FlutterShare2.shareFile(
      filePath: file!.path as String,
//filePath: file!.path.toString(),
    );

Answer (score 0):

We have two different cases:

1. The image is already saved in the device
2. The image is on the network like getting the image link from an API or having the image stored online.

For the first case, sharing it is simple using [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example) plugin like the following:

```
Share.shareFiles(['path_to_image']);
```

For the second case, we have to do the following:

- Read the image as bytes
- Write the image to a temporary file
- Share the created image using the method in 1.

The code uses [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get the temporary directory and the File class used from dart:io so you have to add this to the start `import 'dart:io';`

The code will be like this:

```
// function to get the local path
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
      final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      return directory.path;
  }
// create the file
  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/image.jpeg');
  }
// write the data to the file
  Future<File> writeImage(List<int> bytes) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  }
// the function that you send the link of the image to
  shareNetworkImage(String url) async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    await writeImage(response.bodyBytes);
    Share.shareFiles(['$path/image.jpg']);
  }
```

It will be used like this:

```
shareNetworkImage('https://abdulrazakzakieh.com/images/abdul_razak_zakieh.jpg')
```