# Creating A Share Button Using Flutter for iOS and Android?

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking, flutter

I'm converting some older Swift apps with Flutter.  How can I create a "share" button using flutter that at least gets Facebook and Twitter and make it cross platform for my iOS and Android versions.  Here is the Swift code I use....

```
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem, image], applicationActivities: nil)

        // This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (self.shareBTN)

        // This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
        actInd.stopAnimating()
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Flutter share plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share) -- it might have what you need.

Comment: Thanks @CollinJackson Can I assume these plugins work similar to CocoaControls.com, i.e. custom libraries except for Flutter plugins?  I'll make sure to bookmark the page!

Comment: I'm not familiar with CocoaControls, but flutter/plugins is an open source repository of wrappers around native APIs and SDKs so you can easily use them in your flutter apps. It's maintained by the Flutter team; contributions are always welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 2018, the best way I found was from this SO post here [How do I share an image on iOS and Android using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181343/how-do-i-share-an-image-on-ios-and-android-using-flutter) that requires you use the File Provider package and know a little about Android Studio customization.  Look for the answer from Albert Lardizabal.  Looks like he may be part of the team that made the awesome "Hamilton" Flutter app.