# How to get path from cached images network in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

i'm new in flutter i want to know how to get path from cached images network in flutter or how to save network image to asset image and get the path of that image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. What have you tried so far? Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`cached_network_image`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image#-readme-tab-) uses the [`flutter_cache_manager`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cache_manager) under the hood to save images locally (code [here](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/blob/master/lib/cached_network_image.dart#L470)).

To find the path you need to access the file through the cache manager.

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';

Future<String> _findPath(String imageUrl) async {
  final cache = await CacheManager.getInstance();
  final file = await cache.getFile(imageUrl);
  return file.path;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still have some problem how to make network image to be asset?

Comment: Can you share why you need it in assets? My understanding is that assets are packaged with the app at compile time, as implied [here](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/). However, [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html) they do mention it "could be loaded from the file system", but don't say how. I think they mean you can implement your own `AssetBundle` and set that as the `DefaultAssetBundle`.

Comment: i need it for make an wallpaper app with using network image from api, and use this similar code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181343/how-do-i-share-an-image-on-ios-and-android-using-flutter) and in that code using asset image to share the image between flutter and native java with platform channel, so i think i should use asset image to send my network image, and i don't know how to set asset bundle with DefaultAssetBundle (using network image) code?, thanks for your answer

Comment: In that example the assets are the original source of the image but that doesn't really matter for the rest of the operation. In `_shareImage` they save the image from assets into the app directory, get a `File` reference to it, and then call platform code with the file name. You should be able to do the same, except that you retrieve the file name from `_findPath`.

Comment: so how to make an network image to be file image? so that i can get a file and then call it, thank you

Answer (score 12):

The newer way to do this is using `DefaultCacheManager` from the [Flutter Cache Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager/) package.

```
final cache = DefaultCacheManager(); // Gives a Singleton instance
final file = await cache.getSingleFile(yourURL);
// Now use file.path
```

Comment: `DefaultCacheManager()` does not return a Future. So it should read `final cache = DefaultCacheManager();`. Otherwise you get `'await' applied to 'DefaultCacheManager', which is not a 'Future'.`

Comment: It must be `var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);`

Comment: @Burnash : That is correct. Thanks for pointing it out. From [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Baseflow/flutter_cache_manager/develop/flutter_cache_manager/lib/src/cache_managers/default_cache_manager.dart), we can also confirm that  `DefaultCacheManager()`  gives a singleton instance.

Answer (score 0):

All Cache is stored in one particular place for that app. Any will get trigger their cache for further use. Use flutter_cache_manager to find out data.

```
Future<String> _cachePath(String cacheUrl) async {
  final cache = await CacheManager.getInstance();
  var file = await cache.getFile(imageUrl);
  return file.path;
}
```