# Cannot Share File Using Flutter Channel - Missing Plugin Exception

Tags: image, flutter, dart, share, flutter-plugin

I created **QR code** generating app using **flutter-darts**. Everything is fine except sharing part. I used following code to share my generated **png image**.

```
Future<Null> _captureAndSharePng() async {
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
          globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      var image = await boundary.toImage();
      ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
      Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
      await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

      /*final channel = const MethodChannel('channel:me.alfian.share/share');

        assert(image != null);
        return channel.invokeMethod('shareImage', image);*/
      final channel = const MethodChannel('channel:me.alfian.share/share');
      channel.invokeMethod('shareFile', 'image.png');


    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

When I am trying to share my generated image using above function, an Exception is occuring,

[image: Exception message]

What should I do to fix this. I think this will happen because of the channel parameter.

Comment: MissingPluginException usually occures because you changed your .yaml file, then used the newly added pluging but you did not restart (not hot reload) your application. Make sure to restart your debugging session and it should work.

Comment: I also restart debugging session, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar and found out that the [Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share) `esys_flutter_share:` brings the best method to invoke cross paltform sharing.

Try this code snippet, this works for me:

```
await Share.file(
    'Export', 'export.png', file.readAsBytesSync(), 'export/png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `MainActivity` class also

Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50007287/13617136