# How can I share an image using the share button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I would like to share the image of a card widget along with some standard text using a Share button. While I have been able to convert the card into an image using capturePng, how can I use the result of capturePng to share it as an image via other apps? I'm not sure that the share plugin allows for sharing images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share an image on iOS and Android using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181343/how-do-i-share-an-image-on-ios-and-android-using-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to share files https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share

```
Future<void> _shareMixed() async {
    try {
      final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
      final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image2.png');
      final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/addresses.csv');

      await Share.files(
          'esys images',
          {
            'esys.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
            'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
            'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
          },
          '*/*',
          text: 'My optional text.');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

full example can be found in following link [code](https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)