# How share MemoryImage?

Tags: android, image, flutter, dart, share

I have image from rest API

```
Image.memory(result.bodyBytes).image;
```

I display this image in app.
Wish the user could share this image but i don't know how to do it.

It is only supposed to work on android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share an image on iOS and Android using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181343/how-do-i-share-an-image-on-ios-and-android-using-flutter)

Comment: No, because this is not compatible in AndroidX.