# Selecting picture from gallery/photos and use in my app Flutter

Tags: flutter, share

My goal is to select a picture directly from phone's Gallery and use it in my app, like you would share it with other apps like WhatsApp, Mail, Messenger..etc etc.

I need to:

1. Select the picture from gallery.
2. Select my app from the share dialog.
3. Launch a specific screen passing in the picture.

I've seen a lot of sharing packages but I'm not looking to load a picture by accessing the gallery from my app, but the other way around.

This package https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent seems to do what I need but not in a very transparent and native looking way.. as instead of app icon and name, in the share dialog it shows the iOS extension created for this plugin..

In this post [How do I share an image on iOS and Android using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181343/how-do-i-share-an-image-on-ios-and-android-using-flutter) I see Simon's answer could be the solution, but trying to implement it I'm getting quite a few errors after pasting the Kotlin sample code into `MainActivity.kt` file. I guess it has to be updated.

This is my `MainActivity.kt` file with added code from Simon's answer:

```
package com.vinny.fixit_cloud_biking

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

        MethodChannel(flutterView,"channel:me.albie.share/share").setMethodCallHandler { methodCall, _ ->
            if (methodCall.method == "shareFile") {
                shareFile(methodCall.arguments as String)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun shareFile(path:String) {
        val imageFile = File(this.applicationContext.cacheDir,path)
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"me.albie.share",imageFile)

        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.type="image/jpg"
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Compartir usando"))
    }

}
```

Errors `onCreate()`:
`Cannot access 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleOwner' which is a super type of 'com.vinny.fixit_cloud_biking.MainActivity'. Check your module class path for missing or conflicting dependencies.`

`onCreate: overrides nothing`

Errors `MethodChannel`:

`Cannot access 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleOwner' which is a super type of 'io.flutter.embedding.android.FLutterActivity'. Check your module class path for missing or conflicting dependencies.`

`Unresolved reference: flutterView`

As always many thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share an image on iOS and Android using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181343/how-do-i-share-an-image-on-ios-and-android-using-flutter)

Comment: @Alok Indeed that is the first post I found, but I'm not sure about the answers.. Apart from many answers suggesting their own plugin, there is Simon's answer which also uses `Share` plugin and also provides Swift and Kotlin code. Now my confusion: 1 Can I call question's  `Dart` code from any Screen? eg. the package I linked in my question only handles intents in `main()`.. 2 where do I put Simon's answer `Kotlin` code? Bare with me..I's too new to Android and Flutter. Many thanks.